# Botframework : redevelop the dialog QnAMakerDialog

Tags: node.js, botframework, botconnector

I use sample from Microsoft, i would like to check input , if input
=value use my http.get url else call the QnAMakerDialog.

I appreciate your help.

```
var basicQnAMakerDialog = new builder_cognitiveservices.QnAMakerDialog({
    recognizers: [recognizer],
    defaultMessage: 'No match! Try changing the query terms!', 
    qnaThreshold: 0.3
});

bot.dialog('/', basicQnAMakerDialog);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new root dialog to inspect your message, and if "input = value" then apply your own http service otherwise delegate to the QnAMakerDialog by calling it to add it to the dialog stack with beginDialog.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i don't understand how to develop your answer, i appreciate a sample code

Comment: i do bot.dialog('/', [function (session) {}]) to check input, call qnaMakerDialog with REST API and if qnaMaker return unknow i want to checkLUIS, i don't know how do delegate. may be it is a very basic question, but no way

Comment: When I say delegate, I mean "call a dialog on the stack": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern